# In python 3 what is the difference between re.search(r'pattern, string') and re.search(b'pattern, string)

Tags: python

In python 3 what is the difference between re.search(r'pattern, string') and re.search(b'pattern, string)

I would be interested if someone would kindly point me to where this is documented.

Answer (score 0):

r'pattern' will look into a "raw" string, which if you have backslash, it will not interpret it as an escape character.

b'pattern' will look into a "byte" string, which is a string that is encoded.

So re.search will do the same for both, but in r'' it will analyze a raw string and in b'' it will analyze bytes.

Edit: here is the documentation on it -> [Lexical Analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Comment: Also, `re.search(b'pattern', 'string')` will raise an error: it should be `re.search(b'pattern', b'string')`: strings with strings, bytes with bytes

Comment: “Analyze a raw string” sounds… misleading. It makes it seem like “raw string” is a thing the same way a `bytes` is.

Comment: @deceze I do not think so, as that is what will happen. The function will act the same, but will change what it analyzes. As I understand it, this would be similar to a lambda function. The raw flag will disable any escape codes, allowing the user to look for escape codes for example. While with bytes, it allows the user to look for a specific byte. In both cases the operation is the same, you change the pattern and the type of string you are analyzing.

Comment: @gimix You are right!

Comment: You can only pass a `str` or `bytes` to `re`. The “raw flag” doesn’t change anything about how `re` works. There’s no such thing as a “raw string”, only *raw string __literals__*, which interpret fewer escape sequences and are thus useful when you want to write a string literal which contains many such sequences, which you would otherwise need to escape one by one. It’s just a little syntactical helper. It still results in a normal `str`, and you could write exactly the same `str` as a regular string literal; you’d just need to add a couple more backslashes here and there.

Comment: @deceze I do not see where have I said that raw string are not strings, my point was about the re function, not that raw string were different than normal strings. All I stated was that the difference was in these two "flags" b and r, and that the function did not change, only its inputs. My statement was that with r, you do not interpret escape codes. In this case, if you analyzing text, it can be beneficial to use raw instead of just strings, but once again, regarding re, it will not change, because as you yourself stated, the function only takes str and bytes.

Comment: *”So re.search will [..] analyze a raw string”* — Again, this sounds as if you can pass a “raw string” to `re`, which you can’t, because “raw strings” aren’t a thing. It may be nit picky, but enough newbies believe that “raw strings” are a thing and are somehow different from a `str` that I want to be very careful and precise in the usage of terms here.

Answer (score 0):

`r'pattern'` is a [stringliteral](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-stringliteral) while `b'pattern'` is a [bytesliteral](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-bytesliteral)